# Retrieve the total time CLOCKED over a given interval

Tags: org-mode

**Question:** How can I retrieve, over a set of files `S` (in particular: over my agenda files + their archive files) the total time clocked (as the return value of an elisp function; not as a clock table)? So for example, if I have:

```
* Header1
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2019-05-01 Sat 18:10]--[2019-05-01 Sat 18:30] =>  0:20
  :END:

# File2
* Header2
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2019-05-11 Sat 18:10]--[2019-05-11 Sat 18:11] =>  0:01
  :END:
* Header3
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2019-05-11 Sat 18:10]--[2019-05-11 Sat 18:20] =>  0:10
  :END:
```

I'd like to run a function like `(sum-all-time-from "[2019-05-10]" "[2019-05-12]")` to get as answer ~0:11~.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can sum the times of each subtree within a time range (deprecated):

```
(org-map-entries
 (lambda ()
   (org-duration-from-minutes
    (org-clock-sum "[2019-05-10]" "[2019-05-12]")))
 nil 'agenda-with-archives)
```

---

The `org-clock-sum` function is run on every subtree in the buffer, but since we are using `org-map-entries` we probably only need to run `org-clock-sum` once with the subtree narrowed. If anything this function should run a lot faster:

```
(org-duration-from-minutes
 (apply '+ (org-map-entries
            (lambda ()
              (save-restriction
                (org-narrow-to-subtree)
                (org-clock-sum "[2019-05-10]" "[2019-05-12]")))
            nil 'agenda-with-archives)))
```

Here's an explanation of what each part of the function does: First, [org-map-entries](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-mapping-API.html) calls `org-clock-sum` at each headline of the agenda files and any archive files associated with them, but to avoid repetition, `org-clock-sum` is run with the subtree narrowed. Lastly, we add the time sum of all subtrees and use `org-duration-from-minutes` to get the duration string of the number of minutes, so that 61 minutes becomes "1:01" and so on.

Comment: I think this is correct but it *is* a bit tricky: in particular, it depends on what `org-clock-sum` returns, something which is *not* specified in the docstring of the function (arguably, a documentation bug). I would encourage you to add a couple of short paragraphs of explanation (I would suggest one for `org-map-entries` explaining the arguments and one for `org-clock-sum` explaining what it does and what it returns, plus a line of explanation for the much simpler `org-minutest-to-clocksum-string`). That would make the answer much more self-contained and therefore more valuable.

Comment: This function overcounts time that is nested in subtrees (the further nesting, the more it overcounts). I think I fixed it [here](https://gist.github.com/georgewsinger/68dbcc33519378032d027dbd28014747).

Comment: Can you provide an example where it overcounts? Maybe edit your question and add it?

Comment: I updated the answer. Please test and report back (cc: @NickD, @George).

Comment: Very nice: thanks! I've already upvoted, so cannot do so again. Let's see what @George sees in his tests.

Comment: @jagrg: This function is indeed significantly faster than the old version! I have a [similar](https://gist.github.com/georgewsinger/6c2f962cfd1a86d6e2f31befe2368373) function that is taking 10+ seconds to execute on the same set of files (whereas your function above takes ~1 second to execute). Do you have any tips for how I can speed it up?